# How is y(x) and y similar?

Tags: calculus, functions

In my differential equations textbook, there is a solution of a differential equation as $y(x)=2x+3+c$. From different values of $c$, a family of solutions is obtained. What confuses me is the graph on these calculus books where they have  plotted these solutions on $xy$-plane supposing $y$ as a variable or output of function which is actually a name of function. Shouldn't they have done $u=y(x)$ and then only plot $u$ vs $x$ for the graph of a function obtained?

Comment: Writing a function as a relation $F=\{(x,y)\in X\times Y~:~y=2x+3\}$, writing that two particular elements are related by a function as $aFb$, writing that two particular elements are related by a function $F(a)=b$, having named the function $y$ instead and writing it as $y(a)=b$, writing with $x$ instead and with the other side being the general term as $F(x)=2x+3$, or with $y$ as the function name as $y(x)=2x+3$, writing with $y$ as the name of the second term in the pair as $y=2x+3$... these can all be used interchangeably

Comment: The end result is that the function $f~:~x\mapsto 2x+3$, however you write it, "maps" a particular input $x$ to an output which can be calculated based on the input, in this case $2x+3$.  Whether you think of it as an operation, a map, or as a collection of pairs is irrelevant.  Fundamentally at the basic definition level they are all the same.  Whether you treat the letter $y$ in whatever definition you use as the function name, as the element in the codomain to which an arbitrary element $x$ is mapped, etc... is also irrelevant so long as you are comfortable with whatever choice was made.

Comment: Can you please provide me some resources which mention 'these can all be used interchangeably'? I also don't think y(x) and y mean the same.  y in y(x) is an expression 2x+3 but y in y=2x+3 is a variable whose value changes as value of x changes. Also, y=2x+3 is an equation so y doesn't only have to depend on x, x can also depend on y because this is an equation. So, if y(x)=2x+3 is written as y=2x+3 then we suppose y to be independent variable which is okay because y=2x+3 is an equation, the representation of y(x)=2x+3 as y=2x+3 is totally wrong.

Comment: $y(x)$ directly states that $y$ is dependent of $x$, however, $y = 2x+3$ indirectly states so.

Answer (score 1):

It is a matter of syntax:

For instance, we can write $y = x^2 + 5x-2$ or $y(x) = x^2 + 5x-2$.

The syntax may be differing; however, the semantics are the same. Using $y(x)$ stresses the fact that $y$ is dependent upon $x$ whereas the other does so implicitly . In my experience, $y$ is the convention outside of differential equations but have seen the notation $y(x)$ when in the context of differential equations.  It is not dissimilar to the usage of $y$ vs $f(x)$.

As mentioned in the comments $y$ and $y(x)$ can be used interchangeably.